# Unable to merge android manifests

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was working with [google play services](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) without any problem. after I add [Admob](https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob), I start seeing this issue. I don't know what's the problem. I tried to search about it here, but I couldn't find any working solution. Can you help please?

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/Wasim-PC/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:22, C:\Users\Wasim-PC\Documents\Fly With The Air\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\MainLibProj\AndroidManifest.xml:13] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.google.android.gms.version] element:
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
--    @android:value="8115000">
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
++    @android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:22, C:\Users\Wasim-PC\Documents\Fly With The Air\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml:5] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.google.android.gms.version] element:
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
--    @android:value="8115000">
  <meta-data
      @android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
++    @android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">
]
stdout[

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

is defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml` from the `Assets\Plugins\Android\MainLibProj` directory.

then again as

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="8115000" />
```

in the `AndroidManifest.xml` from the `Assets\Plugins\Android` directory.

As you can see, they both contain different values. This is why Unity is confused on which one to use.

**Solution**:

Keep the `android:value="8115000"` value and remove the `android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"` value.

To do this, simply go to `Assets\Plugins\Android\MainLibProj`, Open `AndroidManifest.xml` file, **remove**

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and **save**. Build your project again and your problem should be gone.

Comment: thanks for your help, I really approciate your help. problem is fixed but it shows different error now. "unable to covert classes into dex format"

Comment: thanks, I just moved to official admob library from google to save my time. everything is working fine now

Comment: You should always be using the official library from google. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue that's because you're using GamePlayServices, it also contains Google Ad Files.

Download latest version of Google Mobile Ads plugin for unity from this link - https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity

(Note - this folder does not have a .unitypackage file, so you need to copy assets folder from source\plugin\ and paste it to your project replace all files if asked by copier. And if you need to import sample scene, copy assets from samples\HelloWorld\ and paste it in your project.)